# Django and VueJS integration error. Error loading VueJS component to Django

Tags: django, vue.js

I have created Django and VueJS integrated project using webpack_loader.
Django runs at localhost 8000 and VueJS at 8080 port. But port 8000 gives me an error in console that
 GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/app.js net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

as I am learning to integrate this two framework together, I followed a tutorial as mention below for this project

https://medium.com/@rodrigosmaniotto/integrating-django-and-vuejs-with-vue-cli-3-and-webpack-loader-145c3b98501a

Thanks in advance

I have checked http://localhost:8080/app.js and it renders a large file, so how come port 8000 cannt connect with it ?

and I have done following changes too

in vue.config.js

change: baseUrl: “http://0.0.0.0:8080/",

to: baseUrl: “http://127.0.0.1:8080/",

and in settings.py change the CACHE value to not DEBUG

Comment: Why do you need to run vue.js on a separate port? Seems to me that you should be using the cli to build the static files (js + css) and make them available to the django framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace all areas of “http://0.0.0.0:8080/" with “http://127.0.0.1:8080/" in your **frontend** app